# mysql query returning "dialog id of specified paticipants"

Tags: php, mysql, message

I'm structuring tables for creating a dialog-look user message function in my OA system.

I got a table indicating participants of a dialog like this
dialog_user:

```
dialog  user
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       3
```

now user 1 send a message to user 2. So I need to create a message, and insert the message into the dialog which user 1 and user 2 participates.

How can i find the dialog id within one or limited queries?

Furthermore, I'm also implementing one-to-more message sending function. Each receiver will see the messages in the dialog which he and the sender participates. So i need to find all the dialogs which sender and each receiver participates, and insert the new message id into it.
Is that possible to be done in one nice-look query?

I've think about save participants imploded-ordered string like

```
dialog  users
1       1,2
1       1,3
```

but i don't think this is a good practice cause the *users* field should be varchar and with limited length(say,255).

Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Do you mean that you are intending to save value '1,2' in a dbcolumn with type VARCHAR?

Comment: yes, but may be '1,2,3','1,4,5,6' as well. but the guy below solved my problem and prevented saving data like this.

Comment: Ok. Good! :-) Sorry I haven't answered until now, but I got sick yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d1.dialog
FROM dialog_user d1
JOIN dialog_user d2 USING (dialog)
WHERE d1.user = 1
AND d2.user = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (assuming DialogId/UserId is indexed):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(DialogId)
FROM
    Dialogs d
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Dialogs p1 WHERE p1.DialogId = d.DialogId AND p1.UserId = 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Dialogs p1 WHERE p1.DialogId = d.DialogId AND p1.UserId = 2)
```